# How to evaluate a glue expression in a nested function?

Tags: r, metaprogramming, tidyeval

I'm trying to nest a function that glues together two strings within a function that uses the combined string to name a column of a dataframe. However, the problem seems to be that the glue expression is not evaluated to a string early enough. Can (and should) I force the expression to be evaluated before it is being passed on as an argument to another function?

```r
library(tidyverse)

# define inner function
add_prefix <- function(string) {
  x <- glue::glue("prefix_{string}")
  return(as.character(x))
}

# define outer function
mod_mtcars <- function(df, name) {
  df %>% 
    mutate({{ name }} := mpg ^ 2)
}

mod_mtcars(mtcars, add_prefix("foo"))
#> Error: The LHS of `:=` must be a string or a symbol

# alternative outer function with explicit enquoting
mod_mtcars2 <- function(df, name) {
  name <- ensym(name)
  
  df %>% 
    mutate(!!name := mpg ^ 2)
}

mod_mtcars2(mtcars, add_prefix("foo"))
#> Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the glue string syntax is now preferred over embracing directly in the LHS. So prefer `"{{ var }}" := expr` to `{{ var }} := expr`. In a future version of rlang (next year) we'll make it possible to use glue strings with `=`. At that point, `:=` will be pretty much superseded. We went with `:=` to allow `!!` injection on the LHS before glue support was added.

Second, your problem is that you're using `{{` instead of simple injection. `{{` is for injecting the *expression* supplied as argument, not the *value* of the expression. Use normal glue interpolation with `"{"` to inject the value instead:

```
mod_mtcars <- function(df, name) {
  df %>% 
    mutate("{name}" := mpg ^ 2)
}
```

PS: Your `!!` version had a similar problem. Because you used `ensym()` on the argument, you were defusing the expression supplied as argument instead of using the value. But `ensym()` requires the expression to be a simple name and you supplied a full computation, causing an error. You can fix it like this:

```
mod_mtcars2 <- function(df, name) {
  df %>%
    mutate(!!name := mpg ^ 2)
}
```

But glue syntax is now preferred.

Comment: I'm working on a full review of tidy eval doc. It'll be live next week, in the mean time you can check the glue doc here: https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/blob/doc-tidyeval/man/rmd/glue-operator.Rmd

Answer (score 3):

`name` is not a symbol. Try:

```
mod_mtcars <- function(df, name) {
  name <- sym(name)
  df %>%
    mutate({{ name }} := mpg ^ 2)
}

mod_mtcars(mtcars, add_prefix("foo"))
```

Even better, tidy eval now supports [glue strings](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/02/glue-strings-and-tidy-eval/) so you could simplify with:

```
# don't need add_prefix()
mod_mtcars <- function(df, name){
  df %>% 
    mutate("prefix_{{name}}" := mpg ^ 2)
}

mod_mtcars(mtcars, foo)
```

Lastly, the curly-curly operator tunnels your expression and you're passing it a string. If you keep your current functions use the bang-bang operator instead:

```
mod_mtcars <- function(df, name){
  df %>% 
    mutate(!! name := mpg ^ 2)
}

mod_mtcars(mtcars, add_prefix("foo"))
```

Comment: Hi LMc, you can also use glue injection with `"{"` instead of `"{{"`, which is now the preferred syntax. We're trying to move away from `!!` for data analysis tasks. See answer below.

Comment: @LionelHenry thanks for your comment and look forward to the release of the tidy eval doc next week. I used the `{{` to allow the user to pass the quoted expression `foo` instead of `"foo"`. I have a usage example in that code chunk.

Answer (score 1):

We may need to escape the input (keeping the OP's original function unchanged)

```
mod_mtcars(mtcars, !!add_prefix("foo"))
```

-output

```
                   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb prefix_foo
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4     441.00
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     441.00
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1     519.84
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1     457.96
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2     349.69
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1     327.61
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4     204.49
...
```

Comment: This seems likely to add more confusion, I'd fix the function instead. The intent seems to be for `name` to be a regular argument, not a defused/quoted argument.

Comment: @LionelHenry that makes sense. thanks